# Using variables in Stored procedures with Python and MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, stored-procedures

How would I setup a stored procedure in MySQL to use external variables.
I have written SP before, but not with extenal inputs. With connection string coming from pyODBC.

Then, using python how would I call that Sp and input that variable?

```
cursor.execute('Call d.MySP' ????)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using MySQLdb, according to [the docs](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html), the call would be:

```
cursor.callproc('d.MySP',args)
```

A peek under the hood shows how the variables are set and the `CALL` statement is made:

```
def callproc(self, procname, args=()):
    from types import UnicodeType
    db = self._get_db()
    charset = db.character_set_name()
    for index, arg in enumerate(args):
        q = "SET @_%s_%d=%s" % (procname, index,
                                     db.literal(arg))
        if isinstance(q, unicode):
            q = q.encode(charset)
        self._query(q)
        self.nextset()

    q = "CALL %s(%s)" % (procname,
                         ','.join(['@_%s_%d' % (procname, i)
                                   for i in range(len(args))]))
    if type(q) is UnicodeType:
        q = q.encode(charset)
    self._query(q)
    self._executed = q
    if not self._defer_warnings: self._warning_check()
    return args
```

Comment: The stored procedure can be defined with a call to `cursor.execute`.

Comment: t, but first, will your code with pyodbc? Then I always use cursor.execute('call d.MySp'). Have a section of code with multiple hits to Db using select's , insert's, UD. But they all use a " % variable" I am tring to move the sql code into the db but preserve the variable nature of the code. How could I do this....Above looks like it would work for python client side but what about server side. any help with server side SP that would take varibles.

Comment: It looks like pyodbc does not implement `cursor.callproc`. See http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/StoredProcedures, http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0249.html.